# How do I put a list item into a table in google apps script(docs)?

Tags: google-apps-script

So there are many ways to go about this, I didn't understand what google's API meant by get child index but I figured it wouldn't do any justice to not even try before I asked.

So this is what I did

```
var line1 = 'n/a'; 
var line2 = 'n/a';
var line3 = 'n/a';
var line4 = 'n/a';
var line5 = ' ';  
var line6 = ' ';    
var line7 = ' ';    

//------------------------Init Functions----------------------------------------------------------//
  for(i = 0; i<8; i++) {
  body.appendParagraph(' ');
  }





//------------------------Secondary Init Functions------------------------------------------------//
  var pArray = body.getParagraphs(); //gets Paragraph
// |Parent/Child

  /*if (pArray[0].getText() != ' ') {        //Mainly to keep with tradition but unnecessary
    line1 = pArray[0].getText();
  }*/

  if (pArray[1].getText() != ' ') {
    line2 = pArray[1].getText();
  }

  if (pArray[2].getText() != ' ') {
    line3 = pArray[2].getText();
  }

  if (pArray[3].getText() != ' ') {
    line4 = pArray[3].getText();
  }  

    if (pArray[4].getText() != ' ') {    
    line5 = pArray[4].getText();
  }
//----------------Re-Assignment--------------------------------------//

 body.clear();
 body.appendListItem(line4).setNestingLevel(1).setIndentStart(72).setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.SQUARE_BULLET);
 var nLine4 = body.getListItems()[0].getText();
  body.appendParagraph("Filler");
 body.clear();
 var tblData = [['red', nLine4]];
 body.appendTable(tblData);
```

I tried to get the modified text as a list so that it would be displayed as a list. This is probably a wastefully complex way of going about this and it doesn't even work

So my question is if there is a simpler way to do this? or is there even a way to do this?

Comment: I have no idea how all of the stuff you've included relates to the question in your title. Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.appendListItem()` or [`.insertListItem()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-cell.html#insertListItem(Integer,String)), depending on your needs, to add the ListItem into the [***TableCell***](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-cell).  In the example below, I'm creating a new table and appending a list item into the first cell of the first row.

```
function insertListItemIntoTableCell() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var table = body.appendTable();
  var row = table.appendTableRow();
  var cell = row.appendTableCell();
  var item = cell.appendListItem("A list item");
  item.setNestingLevel(1).setIndentStart(72).setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.SQUARE_BULLET);
}
```